# Can Windows boot manager remember the last booted OS as default?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, mbr, vhd

Recently, I setup my Win7 notebook vhd dual-boot.
(Copied old Win7 32bit into a vhd disk, repartition and installed new 64bit Win7 into another vhd as new primary system.)

How can I configure bcd to remember the last booted OS as default ? (with timeout)

Is it possible to do ?

Is there any alternative solution supporting vhd boot ?

Thanks.

*p.s.*

*Without "last selected as default", I had to watch console several times, 
while chkdisk C drive, for example. (chkdsk C: /f, reboot, select OS, chkdsk....done., reboot, timeout! & another os boot up, have to reboot again...) irritating. :-(*

*Before VHD multiboot, I used [MBM](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/mbm/mbm_e.html) to select boot partition.
It can configure timeout, fixed default OS, last selected as default OS, 
within the boot menu itself **!**
It's quite handy.*

*I dislike the messy bcd system... ([EasyBCD](http://www.google.com/search?q=easybcd) helps me a lot.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extra old question. BTW, I was looking for this, and found @romka answer interesting. I made some test, and build a simple tool (CMD script + logon task) to automatically set the current Windows instance as the default one.  [I share the repository](https://bitbucket.org/il_mix/bcdedit_default/src)

Elaborating @romka answer, the full command used at startup to set the current Windows as default system at boot is

```
bcdedit /default {current}
```

I run this command via Task Scheduler instead of adding a link in Program Startup since it gives more control on the task, most important when to run it (startup vs. logon) and the privilege level to be used when running the commad (need to have admin rights).

Comment: Elaborating on what you actually did and discovered would be nice and just adding the link for convenience.

Comment: @Seth,  Added some info in the answer (that are on the linked repository, too). Don't get your "and just adding the link for convenience", tough...

Comment: It might have just been my view but your initial answer felt more like a "here is my stuff check it out" kind of post. By including the actual information and providing your link as an addition it feels less like that. I'm not really sure how to express what I really mean, sorry. Anyway good improvement!

Comment: @Seth, no problem, I'm cool. Just thought you meant a further link to "something" could be useful; my misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just don't have dual boot env, so hard to confirm now, but yours seems good. I didn't check bcdedit usage well at that time, and didn't notice about "{current}". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this could work, if each OS on load modifies {default} os selection via bcdedit (must run as admin with elevated privileges):
see "bcdedit /default /?" command

Comment: I think bcdedit /default only can set one <id> entry for default. Do you mean use bcdedit on Win7 start up or something like that ?

Comment: that's right, on each OS startup modify a default OS to be loaded via bcdedit /default. Provide ID entry for the current OS.